# create MySQL dump in pure PHP5

Tags: php, backup, mysql

I'm creating a backup script for my project, which will be executed via cron.

Right now I'm using:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

/* Misc */
$pathtobackup = realpath('.');
$backupfolder = realpath("backup");
$sqlfilename = "SQLDUMP-".date("d-m-Y--H-i").".sql";
$backupfilename = "BACKUP-".date("d-m-Y--H-i").".zip";
$backupfilepath = $backupfolder."/".$backupfilename;

/* Systemcall */
exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u{$mysqluser} -p{$mysqlpw} -h {$mysqlserver} {$mysqldb}", $sqldata, $fp);

$sqldump = implode("\n", $sqldata);

if ($fp!=0){
    die("could not create mysql dump\n");
}

/* Create Zip */
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($backupfilepath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    die("cannot open <{$backupfilepath}>\n");
}


$path = realpath('.');

$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathtobackup, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));

foreach($iterator as $name=>$object){

    $zip->addFile($name);

}

$zip->addFromString($sqlfilename, $sqldump);

if ($zip->close()!==TRUE) {
    die("cannot write <{$backupfilepath}>\n");
}

?>
```

But i would like to create the MySQL Dump with pure PHP to make it more compatible and be able to use it on other servers too, where there is no way to use `system` and `mysqldump`.

I hope you know a solution with out using an 150 file libary :)

Greetings,
Frederick

Comment: I would recommend against it, since dumping a database is a not-so-trivial task, and asking on SO about this does not really inspire confidence. As an example, `PHPMyAdmin` has been doing it in PHP for years, and it has been a source of problems all this time.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do it this way then here are few `mysql` queries that you should consider while creating such script:

`SHOW TABLES` - returns all database table names

`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` returns the sql query used to create a table

`SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` and `SHOW FUNCTION STATUS` - returns list of stored procedures and functions

`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name` and `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION function_name` -return queries used to create stored procedures and functions

The rest are usual `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php ! It is a native solution written in php, with tests, that support stored procedures, triggers, views hexblobs, regexps...

You can install it using composer, and it is as easy as doing:

```
<?php

use Ifsnop\Mysqldump as IMysqldump;

try {
    $dump = new IMysqldump\Mysqldump('database', 'username', 'password');
    $dump->start('storage/work/dump.sql');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'mysqldump-php error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

It supports advanced users, with lots of options copied from the original mysqldump.

All the options are explained at the github page, but more or less are auto-explicative (small snippet from documentation):

```
$dumpSettingsDefault = array(
    'include-tables' => array(),
    'exclude-tables' => array(),
    'compress' => 'None',
    'no-data' => false,
    'add-drop-database' => false,
    'add-drop-table' => false,
    'single-transaction' => true,
    'lock-tables' => false,
    'add-locks' => true,
    'extended-insert' => true,
    'disable-foreign-keys-check' => false,
    'where' => '',
    'no-create-info' => false
);
```